# WCF Services started using more than double memory with .NET 4.6.1

Tags: wcf, .net-4.6.1

We have a WCF Data Service in production which used to use 1500MB memory while running. Web server was having .NET 4.0 earlier.  But since .NET 4.6.1 installed on web servers it started using 4+ GB memory.  There is no configuration or code change in the service but memory usage started more than double. 
the Binding we are using on WCF is as below:

```
<customBinding>
   <binding name="xyz" sendTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00">
      <gzipMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="binaryMessageEncoding" minMessageSize="1024" />
      <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
   </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Is there change in memory management and garbage collection which cause this behavior?

Comment: I probably would have started to be concerned when it was using 1.5GB memory

Comment: This transfer large amount of data to the client.  Data is being compressed before send to client and BufferManager being used during compression.  Custom code is written to compress the data.

Comment: Are you loading this "large amount" into memory on the server all at once or do you stream it?

Comment: No streaming,  buffering